# AngularJS - routing between views with function doesnt work

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have switched to angularJS framework and I have some issues with routing.

This is home.html view

```
<div id="home">
    <label for="priceStart">Kaina nuo:</label><input id="priceStart" type="number" />
    <label for="priceEnd">Kaina iki:</label><input id="priceEnd" type="number" />

    <input type="button" value="Restoranai" />
    <input type="button" value="Maisto tipai" />
    <input type="button" ng-click="navigateTo('/mealList');" value="Ieškoti" />
</div>
```

And this is home.js home controller

```
FoodSearchControllers.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    navigateTo = function(hash) {
        $location.hash(hash);
    };
}]);
```

Can anyone tell me why this doesnt work? Also, it would be good if someone can explain me how to pass variable's from home view to mealList view after this navigateTo() function is called.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ng-click, Your function in should start with $scope.

```
FoodSearchControllers.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.navigateTo = function(hash) {
        $location.hash(hash);
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Well, in that case I get `ReferenceError: $location is not defined` error